# Get image file size from height and width values

Tags: android, image, out-of-memory, size

According to this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object/823966#823966), it is possible to read an image `height` and `width` without loading the whole image into memory.

There is a sentence bit further down in the answer telling that

> bitmap of approximately 512x384. Loading this into memory uses 0.75MB
>   rather than 12MB for the full image (assuming a bitmap configuration
>   of ARGB_8888).

My question is how you can calculate the **image file size (or maybe I must say memory usage)** of the image using the `height` and `width` like in the answer above. Also, what is this `ARGB_8888` value or how to get it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ARGB_8888 is a way of storing information about the pixels.
```

Referring to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config.html) `ARGB_8888` stores each pixel on 4 bytes.

To calculate the total possible size of the image, say the 512x384 example you were using we get the following.

512 x 384 = 196608 pixels.

And we know each pixel is stored on 4 bytes. Thus the total size in bytes will be 196608 x 4 = 786432 bytes.

From here we go and divide by 1024 , see [here](https://4nsi.com/faq/how-do-i-calculate-the-file-size-for-a-digital-image), for every step up the kB, MB, GB, TB ladder we want to go. So to get the MB size for the image we have 786432/(1024x1024) = 0.75.

Hope this answers your question

Comment: Pleasure. Please just mark as the correct answer. Have a nice day.